# RESTful API and Foreign key handling for POSTs and PUTs

Tags: django, api, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm helping develop a new API for an *existing* database.

I'm using Python 2.7.3, Django 1.5 and the django-rest-framework 2.2.4 with PostgreSQL 9.1

I need/want good documentation for the API, but I'm shorthanded and I hate writing/maintaining documentation (one of my many flaws).

I need to allow consumers of the API to add new "POS" (points of sale) locations.  In the Postgres database, there is a foreign key from pos to pos_location_type.  So, here is a simplified table structure.

```
pos_location_type(
  id serial,
  description text not null
);

pos(
   id serial,
   pos_name text not null,
   pos_location_type_id int not null references pos_location_type(id)
);
```

So, to allow them to POST a new pos, they will need to give me a "pos_name" an a valid pos_location_type.  So, I've been reading about this stuff all weekend.  Lots of debates out there.

How is my API consumers going to know what a pos_location_type is?  Or what value to pass here?

It seems like I need to tell them where to get a valid list of pos_locations.  Something like:

```
GET /pos_location/
```

As a quick note, examples of pos_location_type descriptions might be: ('school', 'park', 'office').

I really like the "Browseability" of of the Django REST Framework, but, it doesn't seem to address this type of thing, and I actually had a very nice chat on IRC with Tom Christie earlier today, and he didn't really have an answer on what to do here (or maybe I never made my question clear).

I've looked at Swagger, and that's a very cool/interesting project, but take a look at their "pet" resource on their [demo here](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet).  Notice it is pretty similar to what I need to do.  To add a new pet, you need to pass a category, which they define as class Category(id: long, name: string).  How is the consumer suppose to know what to pass here?  What's a valid id?  or name?

In Django rest framework, I can define/override what is returned in the OPTION call.  I guess I could come up with my own little "system" here and return some information like:

```
 pos-location-url: '/pos_location/'
```

in the generic form, it would be: {resource}-url: '/path/to/resource_list'

and that would sort of work for the documentation side, but I'm not sure if that's really a nice solution programmatically.  What if I change the resources location. That would mean that my consumers would need to programmatically make and OPTIONS call for the resource to figure out all of the relations.  Maybe not a bad thing, but feels like a little weird.

So, how do people handle this kind of thing?

Final notes: I get the fact that I don't really want a "leaking" abstaction here and have my database peaking thru the API layer, but the fact remains that there is a foreign_key constraint on this *existing* database and any insert that doesn't have a valid pos_location_type_id is raising an error.

Also, I'm not trying to open up the URI vs. ID debate.  Whether the user has to use the pos_location_type_id int value or a URI doesn't matter for *this* discussion.  In either case, they have no idea what to send me.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with this kind of stuff in the past. I think there is two ways of approaching this problem, the first you already said it, allow an endpoint for users of the API to know what is the id-like value of the `pos_location_type`. Many API's do this because a person developing from your API is gonna have to read your documentation and will know where to get the `pos_location_type` values from. End-users should not worry about this, because they will have an interface showing probably a dropdown list of text values.

On the other hand, the way I've also worked this, not very RESTful-like. Let's suppose you have a location in New York, and the POST could be something like:

```
POST /pos/new_york/
```

You can handle /pos/(location_name)/ by normalizing the text, then just search on the database for the value or some similarity, if place does not exist then you just create a new one. That in case users can add new places, if not, then the user would have to know what fixed places exist, which again is the first situation we are in.

that way you can avoid `pos_location_type` in the request data, you could programatically map it to a valid ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. How would the API consumer get/know they need to POST to /pos/new_york/ vs. /pos/new-york/ vs. /pos/ny/ vs. /pos/nyc/

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer, but if locations are fixed, then I think exposing the posibilities to the user is the only option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the edit.  Btw, I've edit my question for the sake of clarity.  It's not so much a location (like a city) as a location_type (like: school, park, retail, office).

Comment: Also, I think one of my questions/issues here is that if I add an "end point" (aka resource) to the system, how do they "discover" it.  Or know what it is.  Just by some kind of naming convention?  or again, as I'm thinking about, adding the resources location to the OPTIONS call for the pos resource?